# The implicit conversion of the nvarchar data type into varbinary (max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to perform this query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-update, entity-framework-plus

Follow code:

```
byte[] image1 = ConvertTo.Bytes(Request.Files[0]);
byte[] image2 = null;

ctx
.Users
.Where(x => x.Id == 1)
.Update(x => new User()
{
    ImageByte1 = image1,
    ImageByte2 = image2
});
```

Table definition:

> ImageByte1  varbinary(MAX) Allow nulls?   true
>
> ImageByte2  varbinary(MAX) Allow nulls?   true

I use this one here: http://entityframework-plus.net/

Only problem if I set null to `ImageByte2`. Following error:

> The implicit conversion of the nvarchar data type into varbinary (max)
>   is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to perform this query

Now its I define `ImageByte1` and `ImageByte2` as `null`, it does update normally or `ImageByte1` and `ImageByte2` other than null also does update.

Any solution ?

Comment: Oh, and have you considered an empty byte array rather than a null one?

Comment: @ErikE , yes, I want it to be null

Comment: @ErikE, Post edited

Comment: show your table definition.

Comment: @JanMuncinsky, post edited

Comment: Anything I'm here: https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus/issues/261

Comment: @JanMuncinsky problem has been resolved with the last update. Link: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EF6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has already been corrected with the most up-to-date version.

Nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EF6/